# How to unlist by each row and take unique elements and original size in the list

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I am having a list as row and now I want to unlist all the elements inside the row and take the unique elements .

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
Data<-data.table(
X=sample(1:10),
Y=list(c("between","between","before","pm"),c("am","in","at","am"),c("at","pm"),c("after","after","on"),c("on","am","on"),c("at","between","at"),c("at","between"),c("at","at","on"),c("pm","pm","am"),c("between","between","pm","between","pm","between","pm")))
```

Now I want to get unique elements and also the count of elements in the list .

For example for the first row there are 4 elements present in the list and "between","before","pm" are the unique elements in the list .

So I tried

```
Data[,unique_elements:=unique(Y),by=list(X)]
Data[,count:=length(Y),by=list(X)]
```

But these two give not what I expected, not sure where I am doing the wrong part. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply` to get `unique` values for each `Y` and `lengths` to get length of each element in `Y`.

```
library(data.table)
Data[, c("unique_vals", "count") := list(lapply(Y, unique), lengths(Y))]

Data
# X                                         Y       unique_vals    count
#1: 10                 between,between,before,pm between,before,pm     4
#2:  4                               am,in,at,am          am,in,at     4
#3:  3                                     at,pm             at,pm     2
#4:  6                            after,after,on          after,on     3
#5:  5                                  on,am,on             on,am     3
#6:  1                             at,between,at        at,between     3
#7:  8                                at,between        at,between     2
#8:  7                                  at,at,on             at,on     3
#9:  9                                  pm,pm,am             pm,am     3
#10: 2 between,between,pm,between,pm,between,...        between,pm     7
```

However, this solution is not specific to `data.table`, we can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  mutate(unique_vals = purr::map(Y, unique), 
         count = lengths(Y))
```

Or base R:

```
Data$unique_vals <- lapply(Data$Y, unique)
Data$count <- lengths(Data$Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

A non-`data.table` result

```
lapply(Data$Y,unique)
```

to get the unique strings, and

```
lapply(Data$Y,length)
```

to get the number of elements in the list.